# CSS Responsive Grid System

Tags: css

What CSS responsive grid system have the following features:

- maximum width: 1024px (How to set?)
- 12 colums or more
- nested grid
- image auto-width

I tried [one%](http://onepcssgrid.mattimling.com/), but can't do nested grid.

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) gives you everything you want (plus possibly way more than you want). You'd need to set the max width yourself though. But that would be as easy as:

```
.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
}
```

The [scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) page has docs on the grid.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick I think. I might be wrong about what you are looking for though.

http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs03.php?GridWidth=1024&GridColumns=16&GridMarginLeft=10&GridMarginRight=10

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
 margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

and Check [this](http://www.960.gs)